# Need Month in the range 24th to 23rd

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I want that in my code while reading data from database current month should lie between 24th of last month to 23rd of this month. In other words the calendar month lies in the range 24 to 23.

I am using following code.

Month and Year Calculation

```
<cfset curmonth=Month(now())>
<cfif #curmonth# eq 1>
  <cfset prevmonth=12>
<cfelse>
  <cfset prevmonth=#curmonth# - 1>
</cfif>
<cfset curyear=Year(now())>
<cfset prevyear=#curyear# - 1>
```

this is the query:

```
<cfquery name="GetMonthlySpentbudget" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT 
  IF(SUM(amount) IS NULL,0,SUM(amount)) as monthlyspentbudget 
FROM orders o
WHERE 
  <cfif #curmonth# neq 1>
    if(IsOverBudget=1,
      DATE(ApprovedDate1)>='#curyear#-#prevmonth#-24' AND 
        DATE(ApprovedDate1)<='#curyear#-#curmonth#-23',
      DATE(ApprovedDate)>='#curyear#-#prevmonth#-24' AND  
        DATE(ApprovedDate)<='#curyear#-#curmonth#-23'
    )
  <cfelse>
    if(IsOverBudget=1,
      DATE(ApprovedDate1)>='#prevyear#-#prevmonth#-24' AND
        DATE(ApprovedDate1)<='#curyear#-#curmonth#-23',
      DATE(ApprovedDate)>='#prevyear#-#prevmonth#-24' AND 
        DATE(ApprovedDate)<='#curyear#-#curmonth#-23'
    )
  </cfif>
  AND 
  FacilityID= #FacilityID#
  AND 
  o.ApprovedFlag = 1
  AND 
  o.ApprovedFlag1 = 1
</cfquery>
```

Now i want total month wise in another query .This is the query:

```
SELECT 
  MONTHNAME(approveddate1) AS sMonth,
  YEAR(approveddate1) AS iYear,
  SUM(o.amount) AS TotalSale,FacilityId
FROM orders AS o
WHERE
  o.ApprovedFlag = 1
  AND 
  o.ApprovedFlag1 = 1
GROUP BY FacilityId, MONTH(approveddate1)
Order by FacilityId, iyear, smonth
```

How should I modify the query to get the month in the range 24 to 23?

Comment: Sorry - what? Read this a few times and I still don't get what you mean. Are you saying that you want data from the previous 24th to the 23rd of this month? What happens on Nov 25?

Comment: what about February.. leap years...

Comment: This isn't really a ColdFusion issue, is it? You're just looking for help with the SQL it seems. Also, you've got a number of issues with your CF code, such inappropriate use of #, and not using `cfqueryparam`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT
  MONTHNAME(GroupingDate) AS sMonth,
  YEAR(GroupingDate) AS iYear,
  SUM(amount) AS TotalSale,
  FacilityId
FROM (
  SELECT
    FacilityId,
    amount,
    DATE_ADD(
      approveddate1,
      INTERVAL IF(DAY(approveddate1) < 24, 0, 1) MONTH
    ) AS GroupingDate
  FROM orders
) AS o
GROUP BY
  YEAR(GroupingDate),
  MONTH(GroupingDate),
  MONTHNAME(GroupingDate),
  FacilityId
```